# Unexpected output from parallel programming in Python: am I doing it correctly?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to learn to parallel programing in Python. As a starting point I decided to write a program to test the `multiprocessing` module, before moving on to the 'multiprocess' module (the difference being, I understand, that the range of serializable objects is greater in the 'multiprocess' module, since it uses `dill` rather than `pickle`).

The purpose of this program is to measure the time it takes to square root the numbers in `range(1000)` using between 1 and 7 processes. I looped this program 80 times and generated the following graph.

[image]

I have a few questions about this.

1. Have I implemented the parallelization correctly? It doesn't seem that more processes equates to less time, according to this data.
2. Why are the standard deviations so big?

=========edit======

Question 3 is answered

3. I ran this program two times and both times my computer (with 32Gb RAM, i7 processor and 8 cores) crashed. Why might this be?

Also, if anyone has any further tips about parallel programming in Python, they would be greatly received.

Cheers.

The code i used to generate the data:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy
import time
import pandas
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def sqrt(x):
    return numpy.sqrt(x)

num_repeats=100
num_processors=8

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(num_repeats):
        t=[]
        print 'repeat {}'.format(i)
        for j in range(num_processors):
            if j!=0:
                pool = Pool(j)
                start=time.time()
                results = [pool.apply_async(sqrt, (x,))for x in range(1000)]
                t.append( time.time()-start)
        df=pandas.DataFrame(pandas.Series(t))
        df= df.transpose()
        df.columns=['processor {}'.format(i) for i in range(num_processors-1)]
        df.to_csv(   os.path.join( os.getcwd(),'parallel_p_test.csv')  ,mode='a',header=True)
```

Comment: The "apply_async" method returns an "ApplyResult" object, not the actual result of the computation. You need to call "get" on those objects in order to get the results. Calling "apply_async" many times without "get" may be causing the crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For operations that complete very quickly you will find that parallelisation does not bring much benifit since you will spend proportionally large amount of time with the overhead of process synchronisation.

I would suggest retrying with something that takes a few seconds.

If your computer crashes then there is something seriously wrong. What OS? Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: Do you think that trying the same program but with a larger range of numbers would suffice? I'm using Windows 7. And I'm not sure what/where I would look for a log of what happened.

Comment: no - it is the run time of the function that matters - a larger range of numbers will not help much. try with a function that will take a few seconds at least to complete. how exactly does your computer crash? BSOD? there may be something in the windows event logs - google it.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. I've just tried the program again with a smaller number of repeats and it didn't crash. When I do larger numbers of repeats it tends to freeze up and become unresponsive (no BSOD)  - So I suspect I'm just asking too much of the computer.

Comment: run the thingy that shows the cpu and ram utilization graphs while your run your code.

Comment: Okay, running the code with `sqrt`ing 10,000 numbers uses 100% CPU and most of the memory